# How to add Levinshtein distance on PHP Solr field?

Tags: php, solr

I'm having difficulty converting my query into PHP Solr, specifically the Levinshtein distance. I have this code in the query that works:

```
lev_dist:strdist("mario",first_name,edit)
```

But I am having an error in the PHP syntax for Solr:

```
 $query->addField('first_name')->addField('last_name')->addField('middle_name')->addfield('lev_dist:strdist(franco,first_name,edit)');
```

I got an error on the `lev_dist:strdist part`.

Comment: Post an MCVE (Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lev distance:

```
fname_dist:strdist("<sample text to compare>",<field name>,edit)
```